# Есть ли разница в скорости выделения памяти большими и маленькими блоками?

Tags: память

Возник вопрос касательно работы оперативной памяти и ее выделения приложениям.

Есть программа на JS в которой используется большое количество типизированных массивов. Есть два варианта - создавать каждый массив по отдельности (каждый весит 2048 байт), тогда память будет запрашиваться у системы блоками по 2048 байт. Или же сначала создать объект `ArrayBuffer` (просто участок памяти) на 100 Мб, а потом на его основе создавать массивы (по сути они будут как указатели в C++, создаются путем задания буфера, смещения от начала и длины).

Тест показал, что во втором случае скорость создания массивов примерно в 2 раза больше.

Однако у меня много оперативной памяти на компьютере, и вот вопрос - если есть 100 Мб у системы, но память фрагментирована, то тогда будет уходить время на дефрагментацию? Вообще может ли быть так, что в нагруженной системе выделение памяти блоками по 2048 байт будет эффективнее, чем сразу резервирование 100 Мб?

Answer (score 1):

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос - самописный менеджер памяти быстрее (второй вариант). Опять же таки во втором варианте будет меньше проблем и со сборкой мусора и как следствие - с дефрагментацией.